# How to check what role/clusterrole a serviceaccount is bound to?

Tags: kubernetes

We all know that `kubectl auth can-i <verb> <resource> --as=system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccountname> [-n <namespace>]` can be used to check if a serviceaccount has a specific permission, but is there a way that I can check what rol/clusterrole a serriceaccount is bound to?

Answer (score 2):

```
    kubectl get rolebindings,clusterrolebindings \
  --all-namespaces  \
  -o custom-columns='KIND:kind,NAMESPACE:metadata.namespace,NAME:metadata.name,SERVICE_ACCOUNTS:subjects[?(@.kind=="ServiceAccount")].name' | grep "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME>"
```

Comment: Although a bit complicated and not quite intuitive, it works. I think it's a good idea to add this rolebindingRef field to the serviceaccount primitive just like a pod can have a ownerReferences field